# Verify signed message with M2Crypto for a self signed certificate

Tags: python, openssl, m2crypto

I am trying to replicate this openssl command with M2Crypto

```
openssl smime -verify -in local_files/auth_data.pem.pk7 -inform PEM -certfile certificate.crt -noverify
```

My code looks like this:

```
smime = M2Crypto.SMIME.SMIME()

x509_store = M2Crypto.X509.X509_Store()
x509_store.load_info(ca_file)
smime.set_x509_store(x509_store)

x509_stack = M2Crypto.X509.X509_Stack()
x509_cert = M2Crypto.X509.load_cert(cert_file)
x509_stack.push(x509_cert)
smime.set_x509_stack(x509_stack)

p7 = M2Crypto.SMIME.load_pkcs7_bio(M2Crypto.BIO.MemoryBuffer(cipher_text))

decrypted_data = smime.verify(p7)
```

But I get this error in the last line:

```
PKCS7_Error: certificate verify error
```

I can't make M2Crypto to behave like openssl with '-noverify' flag.

I tried loading the same certificate in the X509_Store but it was the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I took me a while but I found the answer in this source code https://pythonhosted.org/pysmime/pysmime.core-pysrc.html#verify

This is the code to allow a self signed certificate:

```
decrypted_data = smime.verify(p7, flags=M2Crypto.SMIME.PKCS7_NOVERIFY)
```